# Listen for fancybox to open when a page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Im using fancybox 1.3.4, and want to do some action when a fancy box is opened. I searched for answers but couldn't find any concrete one.

for instance in my javascript file i want to listen for fancybox to open

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //example
    when fancybox is opened
     //do something
    });
```

Is there a way?
P.S. I want to be able to do this without updating the plugin.

Comment: It provides several event handlers that you can assign your custom callbacks to ... that not enough?

Comment: @CBroe Yea there are call backs, but i want to do it without binding the fancybox to any selectors. (a general one)

Comment: Can you explain what that means please? How are you initializing the Fancybox?

Comment: You can use fancyBox v3 without initializing, but for earlier versions you have to call $.fancybox() and there you can use any callbacks.